Who first came up with a start date for the commencement of the Laodicea Church age in dispensationalism?
I have heard of the Historicist view see and the Futurist view see of interpreting the book of Revelation.
As far as I know, the Historicist view follows a straight line of continuous fulfillment of prophecy which starts from the time of Daniel, through the time of the writing of the Book of Revelation, all the way to the Second Coming of Jesus Christ.
The Futurist view of interpreting Revelation is very popular today, particularly among dispensationalists. Those who hold this view generally believe that everything after Revelation 3 will be fulfilled in the future.
Clarence Larkin, an American Baptist pastor, apparently claimed that the literal fulfilment of the Church in Laodicea (in Revelation chapter 3) happened in 1990.  Source. Would that be an Historicist view, or a Futurist view?
I would like to know if Clarence Larkin was the first minister to pin a date of 1990 to the start of the Laodicean church age, or if the commencement of the fulfilment of this particular church age happened earlier.
P.S. Found some interesting and useful information here: What is the Biblical basis for a historicist reading of the seven churches in Revelation?

Interesting. As time progresses, historicists keep pushing the start of the age of Laodicea to a later date. I subscribe to a historicist view and I put the start of Laodicea at 1990 as well, based on an analysis of history and using Excel to do a curve fit. Nice that someone else picked the same year, probably following different reasoning.

@PaulChernoch It would be useful to know more about the historicist dates for the start of the Laodicean age and how they have changed. Apparently, Thomas Brightman (1562–1607) branded the Church of England as the 'Laodicean' (lukewarm) church back in the 17th century. Should I edit my question to ask for a history of how those dates have changed?

If you mean a combination of preterism and still to be fulfilled prophecy... I mean that is possible.

This article has useful things to say about the notion that the letters prophesy ages of history: https://biblicalelearning.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Boyer-Rev2-3-GTJ.pdf

What's funny about viewing the seven churches as "church ages" is the last church is lukewarm.  So presumably, those who view them that way would be admitting they're part of the lukewarm church.  Right?

@SLM Tragically we have evidence today of major Christian institutions watering down the gospel, conforming to secular opinions and failing to stand up for biblical principles. Apathy abounds and thousands of sincere Christians are voting with their feet and leaving lukewarm churches. That is why I am not a member of any denomination here in the U.K.

Wouldn't Paul say there's no such thing as a watered-down gospel (Gal 1:6-9)?  It either is or is not, to paraphrase Yoda.  Those leaving a lukewarm to go where?  If the church age view of 7 churches in Revelation is correct, they're supposedly all lukewarm.  Anyway, doesn't matter to the OP, just an observation.  Another question is what does "lukewarm" mean?  Hasn't it existed from Galatians to the present?

Is there something wrong with interpreting the letter to Laodicea as a letter to Laodicea?

@DarkMalthorp The original letter to the church in Laodicea was relevant back then as were the other letters relevant to the other churches. What muddies the waters, spiritually speaking, is the view that there is only one period in time in history when each of the letters had a fulfilment, and that we are now (supposedly) in the age of the Laodicean church. Yes, there was a warning letter to the church in Laodicea back then, and the warning applies to every church ever since, just as all the other warnings to the other churches applies to every church ever since, even now.

@SLM "If the church age view of 7 churches in Revelation is correct..." That is the whole point. The characteristics of all 7 churches has been applicable to the Church since the first century right up to now. A lukewarm church suggests the members of the church are neither hot nor cold for Christ. A bit like "sitting on the fence" spiritually speaking? Perhaps their spiritual leaders have not discipled their congregation, or set a good example, and have become complacent. Yes, lukewarm Christians have existed throughout history throughout the world. All the warnings apply from then till now.

@SLM It is also strange that those holding this view often simultaneously hold to a view in which Christ’s return has been imminent since he ascended. These being separate church ages would fly in the face of such a view of imminency.

I asked Microsoft Copilot and this is its answer:
Several writers have proposed different dates for the beginning of the age of Laodicea, each interpreting the timeline of church history uniquely. Here are a few notable examples:

Clarence Larkin: He suggested that the age of Laodicea began around 1900 AD.

C.I. Scofield: In his Scofield Reference Bible, he indicated that the Laodicean age started around 1900 AD as well.

William Branham: He proposed that the Laodicean age began in 1906 AD, coinciding with the Azusa Street Revival.

Tim LaHaye: Known for his work on the Left Behind series, LaHaye suggested that the Laodicean age began in the mid-20th century.


These interpretations vary, reflecting different theological perspectives and historical contexts.

Another writer was the late Ellis Skolfield (not to be confused with Scofield). In his Teaching Outline on Daniel and Revelation, he has the age of Laodicea starting in 1948 AD.
Adding my own estimate, I choose 1990 AD, based on research that I did for my book Peace, like Solomon Never Knew. The years I assign for all seven ages are given here (without the archeological evidences that I gave in my book):
https://paulchernoch.github.io/paulchernoch/celestial-clocks.html#5
Here is the list from my book:

Ephesus 33 - 100 AD Apostolic but Loveless Church
Smyrna 100 - 313 AD Persecuted Church
Pergamum 313 - 550 AD Compromising State Church
Thyatira 550 - 964 AD Corrupted “Dark Ages” Church
Sardis 964 - 1453 AD Dead Church
Philadelphia 1453 - 1990 AD Faithful Missionary Church
Laodicea 1990 AD - ? Lukewarm Church


This is very helpful.

As a matter of interest, where does Microsoft Copilot get its information from?

Copilot provides links to its sources. I should have included them.

I don't know who down-voted your answer, but it wasn't me!

I started my investigation here  with Clarence Larkin, an American Baptist pastor who was influenced by C.I. Scofield and John Nelson Darby. His major work ‘Dispensational Truth’ (second edition 1920) is in defense of premillennialist dispensationalism.

Like C. I. Scofield, he postulated seven separate dispensations—the current being the "Dispensation of Grace," "Church Dispensation," "Ecclesiastical Dispensation," or "Parenthetical Dispensation." This position held that the church age filled a "gap" in the timeline of biblical prophecy.

Larkin’s book on Revelation suggested the beginning of the church age of Laodicea, the last of the seven church ages, in 1990 A.D.
However, it seems that dates earlier than 1990 for the start of the Laodicean church age exist.  Here is what I found in this article:

Thomas Brightman (1562–1607) was an English clergyman and biblical commentator. His exegesis of the Book of Revelation, published posthumously, proved influential. According to William M. Lamont, Brightman and Joseph Mede were the two most important revisionists of the interpretation and eschatology set down by John Foxe; among Brightman's contributions was to weaken the imperial associations tied to the Emperor Constantine I. The detailed reading, in favour of the Genevan and Scottish churches, and condemning the 'Laodicean' (lukewarm) Church of England, helped to move on the Puritan conceptions of church reform and its urgency.”

Linked to this is a reference here to Joseph Mede:

His Clavis Apocalyptica (1627 in Latin, English translation 1643) Key of the Revelation Searched and Demonstrate, was a widely influential work on the interpretation of the Book of Revelation. It projected the end of the world by 1716: possibly in 1654. The book also posited that the Jews would be miraculously converted to Christianity before the second coming. Joseph Mede held Arminian theological views.

It seems that the historicist interpretation that we are currently in the Laodicean age has been around since the 17th century!  It also seems that the date for the start of the Laodicean age has been changing since then – possibly with hindsight?
It is my considered opinion that there have been lukewarm churches since the first century and I would certainly agree with Brightman that the Church of England fits that description. Whether it started in the 17th or the 20th century is to miss the point – that we should look to ourselves so that when the Lord returns he will not find us lukewarm.

From Christian Workers' Commentary on the Old and New Testaments by Gray, James (1851-1935, published 1915, he posits the church age view.

Seven Periods in the Church.


The seven periods in the history of the Church as outlined in these epistles have been interpreted thus: The epistle to the church at Ephesus represents the spiritual condition of the first period of the Church universal from the ascension of Christ to the close of the first century, the apostolic era. The epistle to Smyrna represents the second period, or the martyr Church, from the death of John to the rise of Constantine, 100-311 A. D. The third, Pergamos, from the state Church under Constantine to the rise of the papacy (Pope Gregory I, 311-590. The fourth, Thyatira, from the rise of the papacy to the reformation, 590-1517. The fifth, Sardis, the Protestant Churches from the reformation to the rise of Methodism, 1517-1755. The sixth, Philadelphia, the Missionary period, 1755, to somewhere near the present time. The seventh, Laodicea, from the present time to the Second Coming of Christ.

The "present time" would be about the published date of 1915.  So, before those in the OP.
There's no reference to those who came before him with the same view, but hope this helps.

Yes, this is helpful.

I don't know who down-voted your answer, but it wasn't me!
